# What is a good, lightweight, Python web development framework that is currently under active development?

Tags: python

As of March 2012, what web frameworks are under active development? Looking to start a new python web project and want to chose the right framework. Preferrably something lightweight and minimally intrusive that would let me use my own database wrapper, sessions engine, etc ...

Comment: There are a while lot.  There's a list of [Python web frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) on the Python wiki that includes the date of the most recent release.

Comment: Voting to close (for now) since this is mostly a shopping list question - see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79835/does-list-of-something-and-why-questions-belong-to-so-and-if-not-then-where). However, I think with some editing to be more specific, it could be a good fit for the Q&A format of the site.

Comment: Here's a [video of a presentation by Richard Jones at Pycon Australia](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYjPIMe0BhA), evaluating ten (or so) lightweight web frameworks.  Bottle wins that comparison.

Comment: "want to chose the right framework", there are several frameworks that are "right" and there are no frameworks that are "right", as far as which ones are under active development, a cruise through github or bitbucket will tell you everything you need to know. Essentially the way this question is phrased you are going to get a lot of opinions about a lot of frameworks and there is already plenty of posts here and on reddit asking the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Preferrably something lightweight and minimally intrusive that would let me use my own database wrapper, sessions engine, etc ...

What comes to my mind is [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It's not under heavy development anymore (AFAIK), but it really is nifty and fun to work with, I can really recommend this.

Comment: Would it be advisable to begin a new project using this framework if it's not under heavy development anymore?

Comment: @ensnare: Hell no, that it is not under heavy development means that it's stable and ready for use!

Comment: @downvoter: please explain yourself?

Comment: because you can pretty much plug in anyone's favorite framework into your answer and it would still be about as true or false as anything else. so in my opinion it is a non-answer just like "What comes to my mind is Bottle or <Anything>. It's not under heavy development anymore (AFAIK), but it really is nifty and fun to work with, I can really recommend this." Hope that helps clarify my feeelings on this matter.